# Create isochrone along a given road

Tags: api, time, route, isochrone

I want to solve this problem :

- given a departure point
- given an arrival point
- given an amount of time

In which areas can I go while coming from departure to destination in the given amoint of time?

For instance, the faster route take me to the arrival in 2 hours, but I have 3 hours. Which areas can I go to with this extra 1 hour?

All I can find is isochrone or isodistance around a point.